# Why does Visual Studio warn me that Administrator permissions are recommended?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-vista

I have UAC turned off and am running VS 2005 from an administrator account and I get this message.  Also, when I try to add existing web site to a solution from VS 2008 I get a message saying I must run VS in the context of an administrator account.

Comment: I tried logging on as Administrator and still get the dialog that says "Administrator permissions are recommended for running Visual Studio 2005 SP1"

Comment: Even though my login is in the admin group I needed to right click and select "run as administrator"  I also needed to uninstall IIS and only install the bare minimum components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though my login is in the admin group I needed to right click and select "run as administrator" I also needed to uninstall IIS and only install the bare minimum components.